# Update query updating only 100 characters to database from 153 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a update statement that will update one column in the database.
The column is defined as `varchar(500)` and the string contains 153 characters.

But while updating, it updates only 100 characters.

The demo script as follow

```
SET @parameter_additional_info = '{optionsUrl:"/api/customparameter/reports/getReportFactoryHeaderTemplate" ,displayProperty : "displayName", valueProperty:"reportFactoryHeaderFooter" }' 

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM [dbo].[t024_report_parameters] 
    WHERE report_id = @report_id 
      AND client_id = @client_id 
      AND report_name = @reportname 
      AND param_id = @header_options_param_id) > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[t024_report_parameters]
    SET parameter_additional_info = @parameter_additional_info
    WHERE report_id = @report_id 
      AND client_id = @client_id 
      AND report_name = @reportname 
      AND param_id = @header_options_param_id
END
```

After update it only shows 100 characters in database as follow

```
{ optionsUrl:"/api/customparameter/reports/getReportFactoryHeaderTemplate" ,displayProperty : "displa
```

[In the database, the column is defined long enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDt7c.png)

I tried updating the schema of the table but that did not work.

Comment: What is the data type of `@parameter_additional_info`?

Comment: Also I strongly recommend getting those upgrade plans finalised and implemented for your 2(?) Instances. Both 2008 and 2008R2 have been *completely* unsupported for well over 3 years now

Comment: In later versions of SQL Server, something like `IF (SELECT Count(*)..) > 0` is automatically optimised into an `if exists()` - I don't think that's the case in SQL Server 2008 so you're query is probably counting all qualifying rows instead of checking for only 1 qualifying row. Upgrading to a supported version should be on your radar.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `@parameter_additional_info` has a length of 100.

For instance, if you do this:

```
declare @test varchar(1)
set @test = 'abc'
select @test
```

It will truncate `abc` and only return `a`, since `@test` is `varchar(1)`.